# I keep getting 404 not found while testing webhook with spatie webhook client and ngrok

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, webhooks, ngrok

I am testing webhook with payment gateway Paystack with ngrok and spatie webhook-client, with my route in the route/api.php. and I keep getting 404 not found at the status response when the event is triggered. But if the webhook route is moved to web.php route I get response 419 unknown state. don't know why.
Please I am new to all these just following to learn.

```
**Route in api.php**

Route::webhooks('paystack-webhook');
```

and **VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
protected $except = [
    'https://17c5dbf1bd87.ngrok.io/paystack/webhook',
];
```

[image: From my Paytack Dashboard]

webhook-client.php

```
  <?php

  return [
      'configs' => [
      [
            /*
             * This package supports multiple webhook receiving endpoints. If you only have
             * one endpoint receiving webhooks, you can use 'default'.
            */
            'name' => 'default',

            /*
             * We expect that every webhook call will be signed using a secret. This secret
             * is used to verify that the payload has not been tampered with.
            */
            'signing_secret' => env('PAYSTACK_SECRET_KEY'),

            /*
             * The name of the header containing the signature.
            */
            'signature_header_name' => 'x-paystack-signature',

            /*
             *  This class will verify that the content of the signature header is valid.
             *
             * It should implement \Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator\SignatureValidator
            */
            'signature_validator' => App\Handler\CustomSignatureValidator::class,

            /*
             * This class determines if the webhook call should be stored and processed.
            */
            'webhook_profile' => \Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookProfile\ProcessEverythingWebhookProfile::class,

            /*
             * This class determines the response on a valid webhook call.
            */
            'webhook_response' => \Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookResponse\DefaultRespondsTo::class,

            /*
             * The classname of the model to be used to store call. The class should be equal
             * or extend Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall.
            */
            'webhook_model' => \Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall::class,

            /*
             * The class name of the job that will process the webhook request.
             *
             * This should be set to a class that extends \Spatie\WebhookClient\ProcessWebhookJob.
            */
             'process_webhook_job' => App\Handler\ProcessWebhook::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

ProcessWebhook.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Handler;

//App/Handler/ProcessWebhook.php
use \Spatie\WebhookClient\ProcessWebhookJob;

//The class extends "ProcessWebhookJob" class as that is the class 
//that will handle the job of processing our webhook before we have 
//access to it.class ProcessWebhook extends ProcessWebhookJob

class ProcessWebhook extends ProcessWebhookJob
{

    public function handle() {

        $data = json_decode($this->webhookCall, true);
        //Do something with the event

        logger($data['payload']);
        http_response_code(200); //Acknowledge you received the response
    }
}
```

**CustomSignatureValidator.php**

```
<?php

//App/Handler/CustomSignatureValidator.php


namespace App\Handler;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Spatie\WebhookClient\Exceptions\WebhookFailed;

use Spatie\WebhookClient\WebhookConfig;

use Spatie\WebhookClient\SignatureValidator\SignatureValidator;


class PaystackSignature implements SignatureValidator
{

    public function isValid(Request $request, WebhookConfig $config): bool
    {
        $signature = $request->header($config->signatureHeaderName);
    
        if (! $signature) {
            return false;
        }
 
        $signingSecret = $config->signingSecret;

        if (empty($signingSecret)) {
     
            throw WebhookFailed::signingSecretNotSet();
        }
 
        $computedSignature = hash_hmac('sha512', $request->getContent(), $signingSecret);
 
        return hash_equals($signature, $computedSignature);
    }
}
```

**Response**

[image: status response from ngrok]

**Route List**

[image: Route List]

Comment: Hello, i'm a newbie to laravel, i have required the spatie package with composer, then add the secret to my env file, and published the database then migrated files,
what i should do next , as long as i used the Route::webhooks('webhookname'); and it's not identified or related to any thing ..
@zahidHasanEmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are mismatching some things here. let's say you want to handle the webhook through web. then you have to put a route in your `web.php` file. (make sure to put it at the bottom of your route file if you use domain routing or to be safe put it just at the bottom)

```
Route::webhooks('paystack/webhook');
```

then add that route to your verify csrf middleware except

```
protected $except = [
    'paystack/*',
];
```

and then your webhook url for paystack will be

```
ngrock-generated-host/paystack/webhook
```

now if you want to handle it through api then put the route at `api.php` file

```
Route::webhooks('paystack/webhook');
```

you need not to put it at the except of verify csrf middleware as it will be handled with api. and your webhook url for paystack will be

```
ngrock-generated-host/api/paystack/webhook
```

Comment: Thank you @zahid hasan emon, I have tried your suggestion with web.php route and I got 500 internal server error response, then I tried it with api route and I got 404 not found response. maybe am still missing something

Comment: do you put the `api` prefix for the api route in your paystack webhook url?? and if you get 500 for web, then it means it's receiving the webhook but something is going wrong when handling the webhook. check the response or the log to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: api prefix? not I didn't, but now I did and is responding with 500 internal server error but I will check the log as you said

Comment: now you are receiving the webhook but something goes wrong when handling it..check out what's going on that causes 500 error.

Comment: I did check the log and this is causing the error                                                                       [2020-12-03 09:54:51] local.ERROR: `App\Handler\CustomSignatureValidator` is not a valid signature validator class.

Comment: your class name and file name looks different..why??

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it and it's working fine now. Thank You so Much.

Comment: sorry to bother you again here is another confusion for me please if u can help I need it, I will be eternally grateful  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65134665/12753944

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'signing_secret' empty => ''